# Gradle Project Sync Fail

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Having trouble while building project in Android Studio.
Getting Error Message :
Error:No cached version of com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project

Screen Shot of error message.

![error-screen-shot]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CpDe.jpg

Comment: Disable Gradle 'offline mode'

Comment: tried but got another error message. Gradle sync failed: Unknown host 'jcenter.bintray.com'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle. Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log). Is internet connection necessary to build the project?